# Next Ajax call doesn't work

Tags: ajax

I'm submitting a form via Ajax:

```
    <form id="ajax-form-next" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="nextPosts" id="nextPosts" value="<?php echo $postIDs; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="actualPosts" id="actualPosts" value="<?php echo $actualPostIDs; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="=>"/>
    </form>
```

In `functions.php`:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {     
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mi-script-ajax',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );     
    wp_localize_script( 'mi-script-ajax', 'MyAjax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_next_posts', 'next_posts_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_next_posts', 'next_posts_callback');

function next_posts_callback() {

    global $post;
    $nextPostIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_POST['cadenaNext']));
    $prevPostIDs = preg_match( '/[0-9,]/', $_POST['cadenaPrev'] ) ? $_POST['cadenaPrev'] : '';
    $actualPostIDs = '';
    $counter = 0;
    $postIDs = '';
    foreach ( $nextPostIDs as $key => $value ) {
        $mypost = get_post( $value );
        $counter++;
        if( $counter <= 8 ) {
            $actualPostIDs .= $mypost->ID.',';
            // Page thumbnail and title.
            ?>
            <article id="post-<?php echo $mypost->ID; ?>" <?php echo $mypost->post_class; ?> style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; margin: 3px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: text-top;">
            <?php
            echo '<div class="thumbnail-review" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><a href="'.get_permalink( $mypost->ID ).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypost->ID, 'thumbnail' ).'</a></div>';
            $audioFiles = get_post_meta($mypost->ID, "pistas-de-audio-mp3", array('output' => 'html'));
            echo '<div class="mp3-audio-files" style="display: none;">'.$audioFiles.'</div>';
            $audioFiles = get_post_meta($mypost->ID, "pistas-de-audio-ogg", array('output' => 'html'));
            echo '<div class="ogg-audio-files" style="display: none;">'.$audioFiles.'</div>';

            add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length', 30);
            echo '<header class="entry-header" style=" padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px ; margin: 2px;"><h1 class="entry-title" style="font-size: 0.7em; margin: 5px;">';
            echo get_the_title( $mypost->ID );
            echo '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->';

            //max longitud artistas
            $max = 20; //define your max characters here    
            $terms = get_the_terms( $mypost->ID, 'Artistas' );

            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
              echo '<div class="artista" style="font-size: 0.7em; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 0px; padding: 3px;">';
              foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_name = $term->name;
                if( strlen( $term_name ) > $max ) {
                  $term_name = substr( $term_name, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";
                }
                echo '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'Artistas' ).'" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
              }
              echo '</div>';
            endif;
            echo '</article>';
            remove_filter( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'max_taxonomy_length');
            remove_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');

        } else {
            $postIDs .= $mypost->ID.',';
        }
    }

        echo '</div>';

        //botones de siguientes y anteriores reviews
        $actualPostIDs = substr( $actualPostIDs, 0, strlen( $actualPostIDs ) - 1 );

        if( $postIDs ) {
            $postIDs = substr( $postIDs, 0, strlen( $postIDs ) - 1 );
        }
        if( $prevPostIDs ) {
            $prevPostIDs = substr( $prevPostIDs, 0, strlen( $prevPostIDs ) - 1 );
        }
        if( $postIDs || $prevPostIDs ) {

            if( $postIDs ) {
                echo '<form id="ajax-form-next" method="post" action="">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="actualPosts" id="actualPosts" value="' . $actualPostIDs . '"/>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="nextPosts" id="nextPosts" value="' . $postIDs .'"/>';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="next" value="=>"/>';
                echo '</form>';
            }
            if( $prevPostIDs )  {
                echo '<form id="ajax-form-prev" method="post" action="">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="actualPosts" id="actualPosts" value="' . $actualPostIDs . '"/>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="prevPosts" id="prevPosts" value="' . $prevPostIDs .'"/>';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="prev" value="<="/>';
                echo '</form>';
            }

        }

        die(); 
}
```

And it works just the first time. The second time I submit the form, it is not sending an Ajax request. The original page is loaded. Any idea of what is going on?
(I know I have to use nonces, but first I want to make it work)

This is the `ajax-search.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var cadenaNext='';
    var cadenaPrev='';
    $('#ajax-form-next').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'next_posts' ,cadenaNext : $('#nextPosts').val(), cadenaPrev : $('#actualPosts').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#posts_container').hide(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {$('#posts_container').html(response).show(1000);}, 1000);
            });
    });

    $('#ajax-form-prev').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'next_posts' ,cadenaNext : $('#prevPosts').val(), cadenaPrev : $('#actualPosts').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#posts_container').hide(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {$('#posts_container').html(response).show(1000);}, 1000);
            });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the "Next", "Prev" links are the part of AJAX responded content, you need to use either [`'live'`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`'on'`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) based upon the jQuery version you are using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var cadenaNext='';
    var cadenaPrev='';
    $('#ajax-form-next').live("submit", function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'next_posts' ,cadenaNext : $('#nextPosts').val(), cadenaPrev : $('#actualPosts').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#posts_container').hide(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {$('#posts_container').html(response).show(1000);}, 1000);
            });
    });

    $('#ajax-form-prev').live("submit", function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'next_posts' ,cadenaNext : $('#prevPosts').val(), cadenaPrev : $('#actualPosts').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#posts_container').hide(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {$('#posts_container').html(response).show(1000);}, 1000);
            });
    });

});
```